# Play notification sound in cordova even though the app is in silent mode

Tags: android, ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, onesignal

I am using **cordova one signal notification** for a security based app. is it possible to play the notification sound even though the mobile(ios and android) is in silent mode. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The point of silent mode is to not have any notifications. So no, you cannot bypass it unless the device is rooted/jailbroken

Comment: But since it is security based app, i need to play the sound with high volume, its like how alarm works even though we are in silent mode

Comment: Alarms run on a separate volume: Alarm volume. The alarm volume is not connected to the ring tone volume, but notifications are.Meaning if the alarm volume is at 0, but notification is at max, the alarm will be silent. Then turn that around, and the alarms will be at max but notifications will be silent.